# Shiny: add regression line without changing data

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I'm writing a Shiny app that adjusts the amount of scatter in a plot. The data are generated via `rnorm()`. I display the plot with `ggplot2`. I want to show or hide a regression line based on the value of checkbox. That all works.

However, whenever I show or hide the regression line (without changing the amount of error), the data are regenerated, which I do not want. I have the data in a reactive function, hoping that would solve the problem but it does not.

I've tried using both `geom_smooth` as well as `geom_abline` (commented out in the code) but both cause the data to be regenerated.

**Question: Can I add/remove the regression line without changing the data?** That is, the location of the points should change only if the slider is changed, but not the checkbox.

```r
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(42)

ui <- fluidPage(

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput("stdev",
                  "Amount of error:",
                  min = 0,
                  max = 0.8,
                  value = 0.34),
      checkboxInput("showLM", "Show regression line?",
                    value = TRUE)
    ),

    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("regrPlot")
    )
  )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {

  output$regrPlot <- renderPlot({

    regrData <- reactive({
      pl <- rnorm(50, mean = 4.3, sd = 0.44)
      error <- rnorm(length(pl), 0, input$stdev)
      sl <- 2.41 + (0.828 * pl) + error

      tibble(pl, sl)

    })

    # For use with abline
    coefs <- lm(sl ~ pl, data = regrData())$coefficients

    p1 <- ggplot(data = regrData(), aes(x = pl, y = sl)) + 
      geom_point()

    # Try with geom_abline
    # p2 <- {if (input$showLM) p1 + 
    #     geom_abline(slope = coefs[2],
    #                 intercept = coefs[1]) 
    #   else p1}

   p2 <- {if (input$showLM)
     p1 + geom_smooth(method = "lm",
                      se = FALSE)
     else p1}

    print(p2)
  })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

<sup>Created on 2019-01-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: You should move your `reactive` outside the `renderPlot`. Then it will only be run if its value gets invalidated. You will always have to re-render the ggplot, however.

Comment: That did it. I thought it had to be something obvious. I tried all sorts of permutations, except that one. Thank you.

Comment: You could also use `set.seed()` before calling `rnorm()`, that way your "random values" are fixed,..

Comment: @BigDataScientist  I included `set.seed()` for the MWE, but you are suggesting that `set.seed()` (when used) should be inside the `reactive()` function instead of its current location? My understanding is that the seed would be set with the initial start of the app, and so should apply to all subsequent interactions.

Comment: first part is correct. It was a bit unclear in my writing, sry. Inside your reactive function is a different environment. Your seed is not defined there anymore,... If you put the seed within the reactive function it should work, yes,....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you put your `reactive` inside your `renderPlot` so that code gets rerun each time the `renderPlot` is invalidated.

Instead, you should move your `reactive` outside into your main `server` function. Then it will only be run if its value gets invalidated due to changes in `input$stdev`.

You will always have to re-render the `ggplot` when you add the regression line, however. So far as I know there's no way to add a line to a `ggplot` without re-rendering the whole plot.

Comment: At one point, I drew most of my plot inside the reactive function, then added the `geom_smooth` layer outside, along the lines of `plot <- reactive({ data and basic plot })`, then `plot() + geom_smooth(...)`. The plot worked but I do not know if it was rendered every time, in part because of my original problem.

Answer (score 1):

Like i wrote in the comment an alternative is to set a `set.seed()` within the reactive function.

Inside your reactive function is a different environment. Your seed is not defined there anymore,... If you put the seed within the reactive function it should work.
Advanced details on scoping can be found here: https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/scoping.html.

An example for better understanding:

```
library(shiny)
set.seed(1)
print("set seed outside server function:")
print(rnorm(1))
ui <- fluidPage(

)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observe({
    print("new environment seed not valid")
    print(rnorm(1))
  })

  observe({
    print("new environment but set seed here as well")
    set.seed(1)
    print(rnorm(1))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```